# How to read file into vector of tuple?

Tags: c++, file, vector, tuples

I would like to read a text file, which contains the following data:

```
Wogger John 2   6.2
Bilbo   111 81.3
Mary    29  154.8
```

The data separated by tabulator. The problem is if the string contains a space (for example: 'Wogger John'), then the program doesn't work. THe program does work if I replace string 'Wogger John' to 'Wogger' or 'John'. How to fix the problem? How to use the getline() function. Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <tuple>

std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, double>> Readfile()
{
    std::ifstream File("file_read_v3.txt");
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, double>> data;
    std::string name;
    int a;
    double b;

    while (File >> name >> a >> b)
    {
        
        data.push_back(std::tuple<std::string, int, double>(name, a, b));
    }
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    auto vt = Readfile();
    
    for (const auto& i : vt) {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ", " << std::get<2>(i) << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't a code issue as much as it is a design issue. Clearly attempting to send `Wogger John 2   6.2` as a *formatted* extraction of `string`, `int`, `double` is not going to work. Whether you realize it or not, you're using whitespace as a delimiter between entities, whilst simultaneously expecting to allow it as part of one of your formatted items. That's not going to work *ever*.  Yes, could could hack up a getline solution that takes action on int-extraction failure, but that's exactly what it would be... a hack.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you don't use a tuple? Point of the question is that it helps to reduce the problem, which is also why a [mcve] is required.

Comment: Maybe a [comma-separated value representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is more suited for your data. It is very hard to parse if it isn't clear how parts are separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (std::getline(File, name, '\t') >> a >> b)
{        
    data.push_back(std::tuple<std::string, int, double>(name, a, b));
}
```

`std::getline` reads up to and including  a delimiter, then discards the delimiter.  It defaults to the delimiter being a newline; here we make it a tab.

Comment: Thank you! It's a good and short solution!

Answer (score 2):

If the separator was always the same, and different from the separator between the names you could use it in `getline` as a delimiter, something like:

```
while (std::getline(File, name, '\t')){
    File >> a >> b;
    data.push_back(std::tuple<std::string, int, double>(name, a, b));          
}
```

But by your sample file contents, it seems that you have tabs and spaces randomly placed, for that reason `getline` wouldn't really help very much, the problem remains.

You could, for instance, read the file `char` by `char` and stop reading when you encouter a digit, put that digit back and then parse the numeric values, roughly something like this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, double>> Readfile()
{
    std::ifstream File("file_read_v3.txt");
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, double>> data;

    if (File.is_open()) // always check if file was opened
    {
        int a;
        double b;
        char c;

        do
        {
            std::string name;
            while (!std::isdigit(c = File.get())) // get character, check if is digit
            {
                name.push_back(c); // add characters until a digit is found
            }
            File.unget(); // put digit back
            File >> a >> b; // parse the int and double
            data.push_back(std::tuple<std::string, int, double>(name, a, b));
            c = File.get(); // get next character
        } while (c != EOF); // if there is nothing else to read
    }
    return data;
}
```

To do, remove the space or tab at the end of `name`.

Comment: Thank you! If I add another condition to the while loop, it will be fine completely: `&& c != '\t'`.

Comment: @Gabriel90 gald you solved it, if the only tab in the line is the one that separates name from values, then it's much simpler, your sample text file, posted in the question, doesn't look like that at all, despite you description hinting in that direction. You can see the below answer also assumes that that are more tabs in the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Thise line:

```
while (File >> name >> a >> b)
```

is causing your problems. You are saying cut my line into 1 string and 2 ints seperated by whitespace, so the line:

```
Wogger John 2   6.2
```

can not be parsed because it contains 2 strings + 2 ints and the stream operator is going to return false and your while loop is exiting.

To solve this natively you need to parse every char until you hit an `\t`. Put the parsed chars in a string, then parse the number until `\t` comes again and parse the next number.

Comment: Apparently there is only one tab in each line separating names and values, making it much simpler, I also assumed that it was more complicated. If that wasn't the case, this would be the correct strategy. And I guess I've been owing 1 for quite some time now ;)